# How to find strings with regex as wildcards with Behat?

Tags: php, regex, behat

I would like to create a Behat rule that allows me to find text with wildcards, since I couldn't find anything close to it.

I sometimes have to create some contents in Drupal projects, but the title isn't defined by the user so I can't know before running the test what the title will be when saved. I.E., in my situation, I would like to check if I can see the following text in the page

> The content 'N° 1', of type 'ISAI', has been created.

Here, I would like to put `N°1` in a wildcard, so I only have to look for

> "The content '/^[A-Z]{1}°[0-9]+$/', of type 'ISAI', has been created."

I started to create a function that looks like the following:

```
And I should see the text "The content 'WILDCARD', of type 'ISAI', has been created" with wildcard matching "/[a-zA-Z °]+$/"

/**
* @Then I should see the text :arg1 with wildcard matching :arg2
*/
public function iShouldSeeTheTextWithWildcardMatching($text, $regex){
  $string = str_replace('WILDCARD', $regex, $text);
  $result = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', sprintf('div.alert-success:contains("%s")', $string));
  echo $result; // is null
}
```

However, it fails because the selector can't find anything with "/" (since it's a regex).

My question is: is it possible to find some text with a regex, and what should I do to make my method work?

Comment: Maybe `@Given /The content '([A-Z]°\s*[0-9]+)', of type 'ISAI', has been created/`, but the function will look like `public function iShouldSeeTheTextWithWildcardMatching($arg1)` (there will only be one argument passed to the function, the `N 1` part). Just trying to tweak examples from the docs, hope it helps.

Comment: No, "$text" is also passed since it's "@Then I should see the text `:arg1` with wildcard matching `:arg2`", plus I tested it, the two arguments aren't null in this example

Comment: Why not just check for partial text in element? or create an Xpath based on 2 texts with 2 blocks of contains like `[contains(text(), 'a')][contains(text(), 'b')]`

Comment: @lauda Could you please give me an example of what you're thinking? I tried to improvize something but I'm too newbie with xpath to find by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the options would be:

**A**
Create a selector based on the 2 partial text and exclude what you would have in the wildcard.

```
//div[@class='alert-success'][contains(text(), 'The content')][contains(text(), 'of type \'ISAI\', has been created.')]
```

**B**
Another solution would be to see if you have a match in the text from this element.

Steps:
 - define a regex
 - wait for success message and get text
 - check if you have a match in the saved text using the defined regex

> Your string/regex can be created using variables if needed. Use echo to mage sure your selector is valid. Make sure the page is loaded.

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm still getting errors, see my updated question

Comment: Nevermind, my code was wrong with the example I was using, it works, thank you!